# How can I set the vertical margin of my chapter headings?

Tags: sectioning, vertical-alignment, chapters, koma-script

I currently don't like the typesetting of a document. In my two sided document, I want that the chapter headings not have a vertical space before their appearance.

The text on the second page should start at line 1 or if it's possible on line 2.

My document preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,parskip=half,a4paper,twoside]{scrreprt}
[..]
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
[..]
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{1em}

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0em}{1em}{0em}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
[..]
\end{document}
```

[image: Margin]

Comment: I see *no* vertical space before the chapter title.

Comment: On the second page appear the text before the chapter heading on the first page. How can I make that everything on the same vertical position starts?

Comment: Oh, yeah! That's not the heading, but a subsection title.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try with

```
\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-2\baselineskip}}
```

in your document preamble.

When using **titlesec** as you do, write

```
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-2\baselineskip}{1em}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it does not work. I use the package `titlesec`. Is this might the problem?

Comment: @Sam If you want help about this you should show the relevant parts of your preamble.

Comment: Your solution works when I don't use `titlesec`. I've updated my question. I think that's all, what is in context with my problem.